# Check if a type is passed in variadic template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, c++17

I've heard somewhere, that using new C++1z syntax, it is really easy to check if a type is passed in variadic template parameter pack - apparently you can do this with code that is near one-line long. Is this true? What are those relevant features? (I tried looking through fold expressions but I can't see how to use them in that problem...)

Here's how I solved the problem in C++11 for reference:

```
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct contains;

template<typename T>
struct contains<T> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
struct contains<T1, T2, Ts...> {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T1, T2>::value ? true : contains<T1, Ts...>::value;
};
```

Comment: Earlier I didn't see the part where you said you couldn't figure out the fold expression syntax for doing this, I've added an example for that too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction). It's specified in [N4564](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4564.pdf) *[meta.logical]*.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool contains()
{ return std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>; }

static_assert(    contains<int,      bool, char, int, long>());
static_assert(    contains<bool,     bool, char, int, long>());
static_assert(    contains<long,     bool, char, int, long>());
static_assert(not contains<unsigned, bool, char, int, long>());
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J6HFYFRgGhrg0EpD)

---

Or, adapted to a `struct`

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct contains : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>
{};
```

---

Or, using fold expressions

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct contains : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same<T, Ts>{} || ...)>
{};
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QMnPq13uQYylj7Kx)

Comment: Good one ! I usually see value metafunctions delegated by inheritance, it's quite a bit shorter : `template<...> struct contains : std::disjunction<...> {};`

Comment: @Quentin Thank you, much better. I was too intent on using `disjunction_v` from the function version :)

Comment: In your fold expression - `struct contains : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same<T, Ts>{} || ...)>` - what does syntax `std::is_same<T, Ts>{}` mean? (I mean, `std::is_same<T,Ts>` is a struct which contains true or false value in its `value` member variable. On which  syntax rule do `{}` extract this `value` from the struct?)

Comment: @qiubit The `{}` is *direct-list-initializing* the `is_same` instance, in other words, constructing it. [`is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) has an implicit boolean conversion operator which it inherits from `integral_constant`, so that expression yields a boolean value. You could also write `std::is_same<T, Ts>::value` instead.

Comment: Since we are in 17 territory with the fold expression, we might as well just write `is_same_v`.

Comment: Fold expressions looks as most natural and fast way.

Answer (score 3):

If you are bound to C++11 you cannot use `std::disjunction` nor fold-expressions. However, it is rather straightforward to roll your own `any_is_same`:

```
template<typename same, typename first,typename...more> 
struct any_is_same {
    static const bool value = std::is_same<same,first>::value || 
                              any_is_same<first,more...>::value; 
};

template<typename same,typename first> 
struct any_is_same<same,first> : std::is_same<same,first> {};


int main(){
    std::cout << any_is_same<int, int,double,float>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << any_is_same<std::string, int,double,float>::value << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IcMzWgAhj5OYoIbS)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880262/12002570). You might want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment to the C++11 version posted by 463035818_is_not_a_number, but commenting requires 50 reputation...

It has a small bug in it, the correct code is:

```
    template<typename same, typename first,typename...more> 
struct any_is_same {
    static const bool value = std::is_same<same,first>::value || 
                              any_is_same<same,more...>::value; 
};
```

is the correct one, note the difference of the `any_is_same` call's first parameter which has to be `same`, not `first`.

Comment: I've added a comment below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392578/12002570) for you.