# Is Parameter pack contained in other Parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm writing a class that manages a function object(for fun:)).

I want a templated member function of a templated class to check if all of the types given to it were already given to the class.

```
template<typename... Args>
class funclass
{
    public:
    template<typename... types>
    void funfun ()
    {
        static_assert(/*is every type in types contained in Args*/);
    }
};
```

Comment: The simple solution is an iterative application of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099597/check-if-a-type-is-passed-in-variadic-template-parameter-pack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper to check if a given `T` is part of the `Args...` pack:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct contains {
    static constexpr bool value = (std::is_same<T,Args>::value || ...);
};
```

Then check it for all types in `types...`:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct funclass
{
    template<typename... types>
    void funfun ()
    {
        constexpr bool contains_all = (contains<types,Args...>::value && ...);
        static_assert( contains_all  );
    }
};

int main() {
    funclass<int,double>{}.funfun<int>(); // OK
    funclass<int,double>{}.funfun<float>(); // error
}
```

Comment: Can ```contains``` be a ```consteval``` function? (And I think that you can use std::disjunction and std::conjunction right?

Comment: @EyalKamitchi yes it could be a function, though I have zero experience with `consteval`. I also don't know `std::disjunction` or `std::conjunction` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce them to be in the same order too, you can generate two `tuple` types then compare them, as follows

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
template<typename... Args>
struct Fun{
    template<typename... types>
    void fun (){
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<Args...>,std::tuple<types...>>);
    }
};
int main(){
    Fun<int,bool>{}.fun<int, bool>();//passes
    Fun<int,bool>{}.fun<int, bool, double>();//fails

}
```